# average of .txt file with str and int within it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a function that reads a `.txt` file that contains the following:

Testing.txt:

```
a 1 34
b 2 25
c 3 23
j 4 80
```

I need to create a function that reads this file and prints the average of the last 2 digits of each line in the file.

What I have so far is this:

```
def Stats():

    filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = [int(line) for line in f]

    print("The average value is ", sum(data)/len(data))


Stats()
```

Pros:

- this function will produce the average of int values within a function.

cons:

- It will not work if the file contains str within it.

Question: How can I get my function to work with a file such as the one listed above called (testing.txt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
# filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
filename = "input.txt"

def avg_file(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = [int(line.split()[2]) for line in f]
        return sum(data)/len(data)


avg =  avg_file(filename)

print("The average value is: ", avg)
# The average value is:  40.5
```

the key is this `line.split()[2]`. This splits a line based on spaces, and takes 3th value.

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore non-numbers this way:

```
data = [int(token) for token in f.read().split() if token.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
import csv

def mean(lst): return sum(lst) / len(lst)

with open('input.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    lines = [line for line in reader]

col3 = [int(line[2]) for line in lines]

print(mean(col3))  # 40.5
```

This just uses the csv module to parse the file lines into rows containing elements.  You could accomplish the same thing with something like:

```
def mean(lst): return sum(lst) / float(len(lst))

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.split() for line in f]

col3 = [int(line[2]) for line in lines]

print mean(col3)  # 40.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
data = [sum(map(int, line.split(' ')[1:])) / 2 for line in f]
```

Or something more old-school, in case you have unknown mix of string and int values:

```
data = []
for line in f:
    integers = []
    for segment in line.split():
        try:
            integers.append(int(segment))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.append(sum(integers) / len(integers))
```